# Memory usage exceeds limit in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, doctrine, bjyauthorize

I am using Zend Framework 2.0 with Bjyauthorize in my localhost. I am unbale to get the output due to one Fatal Error as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV3C5.png)

I am using xampp 3.2.1 in Windows 7 and my source code was located at different directory instead of xampp/htdocs/.

I have created virtual host in hosts file and configured domain like ab.testdemo.com which points to public directory of zend framework in httpd-vhost.conf file.

I have already set below php settings in my php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = -1 
max_execution_time=0
post_max_size=6000M
upload_max_filesize=128M
```

Can anyone have any solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you amended the `php.ini` in the Apache folder, thats the one that effects Apache. Not the one in the `php` folder. I assume you restarted Apache after the change?

Comment: Did you update the correct php.ini file? Did you restart your webserver afterwards?

Comment: Yes i have updated correct php.ini file and i have restarted apache web server.

Comment: Use phpinfo() to check your settings, incuding the location of the ini file

Comment: I have checked using phpinfo() and it was showing the reflections which i have made earlier in php.ini which is located at 'D:\xampp\php\php.ini'. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84gmW7dE18HdWVVR1ZQbmpNSEU/view?usp=drivesdk)